# Loop throuh all members of site in WordPress/WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display all members of my site.

As I understand the WooCommerce Membership plugin, the members are stored as custom post type (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-data-structure/#section-4) and I could get them with `get_posts()`.

I tried to do so with the following code:

```
<ul class="my-5">
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'wc_user_membership' );
$posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $posts as $post ) : 
    setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li><?php echo $post->ID; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately without any result.
Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

Try to add in your `$args` array `'numberposts' => -1` and `'post_status' => 'wcm-active'` so your code will be:

```
<ul class="my-5">
<?php
$posts = get_posts( array( 
    'post_type' => 'wc_user_membership', 
    'post_status' => 'wcm-active',
    'numberposts' => -1,
) );

foreach ( $posts as $post ) :
    setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li><?php echo $post->ID; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

You don't need  `global $post;` as you are using `$post` in the `foreach` loop.

Tested and works.

Comment: that's not helping :( I guess the post type wc_user_membership is not usable in the frontend. I tried to get all authors of this post type with a function that works for other post types. In this case it also shows no results.

Comment: It is in the table?!

Comment: OK. I will check my site again

Comment: Updated and working … You need also to specify the post_status (or the statuses in an array when multiple)

Comment: that's it. Thanks!